# Php empty result after execution

Tags: php

```
    <?php
require_once 'init.php';

if(isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'])) {

$extractInfoUser = $db->prepare("
    SELECT * FROM user
    WHERE username = :username
");

$extractInfoUser->execute([
    'username' => $_POST['username']
]);

$users = $extractInfoUser->rowCount() ? $extractInfoUser : [] ;

foreach ($users as $user) {
    if ($user['username'] = null) {
        die("There is no username like this !");
        } else {
            echo "You are not able to register under this username !";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

**The problem is that I get as result *nothing* ! 
Please help cuz I can't find this error ! I have no idea what it can be !**

Comment: First of all check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did an assignment instead of a comparison so change this if statement:

```
if ($user['username'] = null)
```

to this:

```
if ($user['username'] == null)
                    //^^ See here 2x '='
```

Answer (score 3):

Your IF statement is wrong, you're setting instead of checking.

```
if ($user['username'] = null) {
```

While you should do:

```
if ($user['username'] == null) {
```

You forgot to put double = operator, instead of checking you were setting $user['username'] to false.

Comment: @DenisDumitras Do a echo after the `foreach` header and look if you even enter the foreach loop

Comment: @Rizier123 I can't even echo sth !

Comment: @DenisDumitras Do a echo after the first if statement, i think you don't even enter this

Comment: After first statement I can echo $_POST['username'] for example !

Comment: @DenisDumitras Then print this: `echo $extractInfoUser->rowCount();` I think this is 0 and you get an empty array

Comment: @DenisDumitras There you go! Either your query/connection fails or you just have no entries in your db

Comment: @Rizier123 Thanks now I understood the error I'll try to fix it !